# Solving differential equation $x'' + w^2x = \Omega^2x^{-3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation ? [both $\Omega^2$ are constants and differentiation is w.r.t to $t$]

I found the complementary solution, but how to find the particular solution? I haven't solved D.E with negative power of $x$.

$$\ddot{x}+w^2x=\Omega^2x^{-3}$$

Comment: There is no "complementary solution": this is not a linear differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch variables, you face
$$\frac {t''}{[t']^3}-w^2 x+\frac{\Omega ^2}{x^3}=0$$ First, reduction of order $p=t'$ leads to
$$p=t'=\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{-w^2 x^4+c_1 x^2-\Omega ^2}}$$
$$t+c_2=\pm\int   \frac{x}{\sqrt{-w^2 x^4+c_1 x^2-\Omega ^2}}\,dx$$ Let $x=\sqrt y$ to face a simple integral (complete the square).

May be, the inversion could not be very easy using this simple way. But this part is easy to do by hand.

Otherwise, $x$ is given as a Jacobi elliptic function (which is not the most pleasant result)
$$x=\pm i \sqrt{\frac{-w^2+\sqrt{w^4-2 c_1 \Omega ^2}}{\Omega ^2}} \,\,\times $$ $$   \text{sn}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(t+c_2){}^2 \left(w^2+\sqrt{w^4-2 c_1
   \Omega ^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}|\frac{w^4-w^2 \sqrt{w^4-2 c_1
   \Omega ^2}-c_1 \Omega ^2}{c_1 \Omega ^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The command of Maple 2023

```
dsolve((D@@2)(x)(t) + w^2*x(t) = Omega^2/x(t)^3)
```

results in $$x\! \left(t\right) {=} -\frac{\sqrt{-c_{1} \left(16 c_{1}^{2} c_{2}^{2} w^{2}-8 {\mathrm e}^{-2 \,\mathrm{I} w t} c_{1}^{2} c_{2} w-64 \Omega^{2} w^{2}+\left({\mathrm e}^{-2 \,\mathrm{I} w t}\right)^{2} c_{1}^{2}\right)}}{4 c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{\mathrm{-I} w t} w},
\\
x\! \left(t\right){=}\frac{\sqrt{-c_{1} \left(16 c_{1}^{2} c_{2}^{2} w^{2}-8 {\mathrm e}^{-2 \,\mathrm{I} w t} c_{1}^{2} c_{2} w-64 \Omega^{2} w^{2}+\left({\mathrm e}^{-2 \,\mathrm{I} w t}\right)^{2} c_{1}^{2}\right)}}{4 c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{\mathrm{-I} w t} w} $$

Comment: The command `odetest(x(t) = -sqrt(-c__1*(16*c__1^2*c__2^2*w^2 - 8*exp(-2*I*w*t)*c__1^2*c__2*w - 64*Omega^2*w^2 + exp(-2*I*w*t)^2*c__1^2))/(4*c__1*exp(-I*w*t)*w), (D@@2)(x)(t) + w^2*x(t) = Omega^2/x(t)^3)` results in $0$, confirming the first solution. The same with the second one.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this by hand ?

Comment: I tried solving by variation of parameters method, I didn't get the solution

Comment: @kumar: Did you look in the handbook by E. Kamke?

Comment: Could you tell me name of the book ?

Comment: @kumar:  See [that](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18237747-differentialgleichungen-losungsmethoden-und-losungen).

Comment: @kumar: Variation of parameters only works for *linear* ODEs. But your ODE has the form $x''=V(x)$ (which is a standard Newton-type equation from physics), so you can multiply by $x'$ and integrate, and then solve for $x'$ to get a separable equation $dx/dt = \pm \sqrt{f(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

After multiplying by $\dot x$ we have

$$
\frac 12(\dot x^2)'+\frac 12(w^2x^2)'+\frac 12\Omega^2(x^{-2})' = 0
$$

then

$$
\dot x = \sqrt{c - w^2x^2-\Omega^2x^{-2}}\Rightarrow dt = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c - w^2x^2-\Omega^2x^{-2}}}
$$

etc.